# How can I fit svg path to certain px size without javascript

Tags: css, svg

```
<div style="width:40px;
            height:40px;
            background: #333333;
            margin: 10px;">

    <svg version="1.1" 
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
         width="40" 
         height="40" 
         style="width:40px; 
         height:40px;" 
         viewBox="0 0 40 40" 
         preserveAspectRatio="none">

         <g transform="translate(20, 20)">
             <path fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" d="M-10,-10h20v20h-20z"></path>
         </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fz4rc/

The first path is too small, the second path is too large.

I have looked into few related questions on SO.
I have tried playing with viewBox, preserveAspectRatio, width, height.

How can I get both paths to fit 40px size (either svg or div) without measuring the BBox in javascript? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `width` and `height` attributes of an SVG container define the size of the container. The `viewBox` attribute defines the part of the SVG drawing that will be visible in the container. To get both paths fitting `40px` size, you need to set `width` and `height` to `40px` and set the parameters of `viewBox` such that the rectangle it defines contains the whole shape.
If you do not know the size of your shape initially, i think you can not avoid the use of `getBBox()` or other similar stuff.
Your demo with corrected values : http://jsfiddle.net/Fz4rc/1/

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It would be brilliant if there was a way of doing something like viewBox="auto" :)